# Pi connected to local network with ethernet but can't connect to the Internet

Tags: networking, ethernet, vpn, ping

I recently tried to install OpenVPN on my pi. Since then I've been having trouble with the networking in my Pi. I already removed it and purged it.

I can ssh into my Pi fine (my home network is in perfect condition). But when I try to ping Google it says `ping: unknown host google.com` Also, whenever I try to use the internet some other way I can't do anything.

How can I solve this? What do I need to do to make a diagnostic?

Comment: Can you ping 8.8.8.8 (Google's public DNS)? If you get a response its likely a DNS issue, otherwise its likely a routing issue. Both solveable.

Comment: It is a DNS issue. I can ping Google's DNS just fine. How would I solve this?

Comment: When you installed OpenVPN what else did you do? I'm guessing set a static IP? DNS-wise you might want to check the contents of resolv.conf `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and if its empty `sudo -c "echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf"` then try pinging Google by name. `resolv.conf` is regenerated on boot (usually, unless thats disabled). If you have a static IP that you set in `/etc/network/interfaces` you might want to check it has a nameservers line, you'd usually get provided DNS records from your DHCP server / router.

Comment: I try it an it gives me `-bash: /etc/resolv.conf: Permission denied`

Comment: I do it and it fixes the issue for a moment but somehow the `resolv.conf` gets overwritten after a moment and the problem continues

Comment: What is getting written into the `resolv.conf` file? It might help determine what is updating it. Do you have this set for static up or dynamic?

Comment: It says `# Generated by resolvconf`

Comment: Are you using a static IP?